# Linux user groups missing when user mounted to container

Tags: linux, docker, usergroups

**Issue**: The groups attached to a Linux user are not visible inside the container.

**Workflow:**

1. Created a docker image, in which a `user` and `group` named `sample:sample(8000:8000)` is created.
2. Created a container using the same docker image and mounted the `/etc/passwd` file with `readOnly` access.

```
Command: docker run -itd --user "8000:8000" -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro docker_image_name:latest bash
```

**Note:** The user & group sample:sample(8000:8000) also exists on the host.

3. The groups attached with sample user are sample and docker as checked on the host using the groups command.
4. Execed into the container and fired the following commands,

```
Command 1: whoami
Output: sample
Command 2: id -u
Output: 8000
Command 3: id -g
Output: 8000
Command 4: groups
Output: sample
```

**Observations:**

1. As we can see, within the container the groups attached to sample user is only sample and docker is missing.

**Expected Behaviour:**
As the sample user is present on host as well as the container, I want the groups associated with the host user inside the container as well, i.e., I want the host user details to override the ones present in the container.

Comment: Maybe you can try mounting /etc/group.

Comment: Information about supplementary user groups membership is stored in `/etc/group`. You need to map it as well, as Philippe advised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue lies in the way Docker loads the user and group information.

Issues are already reported to Docker as it fails to load the additional groups information which is stored in `/etc/groups` file, so, even if we mount the `/etc/groups` file Docker doesn't honor it.

Hence, the solution is to associate the required groups using the `--group-add` option provided by docker.

Note: This group provided must be a valid group and it will then be associated to your user with the already existing groups.

Comment: Can you link the issues where this has been reported? Or the section in the documentation that describes this?

Comment: Is this related to https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3012 then?